# Запрет на ввод знака "минус" в input страницы (JSF)

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Нужно сделать запрет на ввод знака "минус" в поле input. Страница написана с использованием JSF и Primefaces. Нужна не просто валидация, а чтобы поле вообще не реагировало на нажатие этого символа.

Answer (score 0):

Данную проблему решает keyFilter. К примеру, данный кусок кода разрешает ввод только A, B, C.

```
<p:keyFilter regEx="/[ABC]/i"/>
```

Может кому-нибудь пригодиться.